# Dark transitions between contrasting colors, what is it and how to avoid it?

Tags: adobe-illustrator, color-profile, anti-aliasing

I've got this issue where I have a teal background and a fuchsia foreground, and when exporting, the anti-aliasing between the two leaves a dark transition. I've found a few workarounds, one of which is exporting upscaled without anti-aliasing and downscaling it in Photoshop with a ProPhoto RGB color profile, the other of which is using ProPhoto RGB color profile in Illustrator, and using "Save for Web" to export it, which seems to yield better results.

Is there a name for this phenomenon? Is there a good solution other than multi-step exports or using a legacy export option?

---

Images of desirable and undesirable blending respectively:

[image: Correct anti-aliasing][image: Incorrect anti-aliasing]

Comment: Hi. Welcome to GDSE. Why are you zooming in on a raster image?  View it at 100% instead.  TBH I doubt very much if the difference will be that noticeable. If anything the second version with the darker blueish transition may look slightly sharper.  Why is this undesirable?

Comment: I did view it at 100% which is how I noticed it. I don't know how to justify my aesthetic preference, but it stands to reason that a transition from one color to another shouldn't result in a pixel with lower lightness than both of the original colors.

Comment: Well, adobe does do this blending naively in working space. So if you use a linear RGB space then you get different feel.